# How get ImageView from ListView item?

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview

I have a list Activity and I want set image resource to Image view in list view item.

```
        ListView listView = getListView();
        View view = listView.getChildAt(0);
        arrowImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.arrowImageView);
```

but getChildAt(0) return null. List have 10 items.
How i can find a ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**
I think you're asking how to set an image resource in each item of your list view? If so, extend your SimpleCursorAdapter and override getView similar to this:

```
// Create the list adapter
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        CfsApplication.getApplication(),
        R.layout.listitem_vehicledraft,
        VehicleDraftTable.getAllVehicleDrafts(),
        displayFields,
        displayViews) {
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the view from the super function which will handle most of everthing for us
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Set the image view here
                    // ...

        // Return the view
        return convertView;
    }
};
```

Comment: I didn't say to create a new one, I said to override the getView method so you can set your image views...